# Viewpager taking all remaining height in screen even if it's height is wrap content

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-xml

I have defined my viewpager in XML like this :

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >   
     ......................

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_grid_calendar_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="#387"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And my child fragment layout looks like this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/dash_board_grid_calendar_recycler_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_grid_calendar_cell"
    />
```

But when I run the app the viewpager takes all the height due to which the color #387 is all over the screen.

[image]

What might be going wrong?

Comment: share complete xml....

Comment: I have updated the layout

Comment: @Enzokie there you go :)

Comment: the view you are placing inside viewpager may be causing problem. check if the fragment or something you have used has parent layout set to match parent.

Comment: I have updated the question and added child layout too. But my child layout has wrap content

Comment: Just try giving a fixed size to viewPager

Comment: But In my case I cannot, because the height can be variable

Comment: I even tried giving fixed height but it does not work. I think it did but I was wrong. It does not help changing to fixed height

Comment: @erluxman yes obliviously you have to give fixed height to viewPager and the child i.e recycleView will be affected accordingly....

Comment: even after giving fixed height to viewpager i still get the viewpager, covering all the screen until the end.

Comment: try giving both fixed height

Comment: There must be sth wrong with IDE, i changed the background color but it is not chaning...

Comment: I invalidated the cache and restarted, When I set the fixed height for viewpager it works.. But wrap_content Does not work..